# Unwrapping optionals causing crash seem counter intuitive

Tags: swift, option-type

I know Swift has a rule that says if you try to unwrap an Optional that contains a `nil`, it crashes.

Just a thought, if I want a type to be Optional (allow `nil` or a value), why would I want my program to crash if I unwrap it even if I explicitly say `nil` is allowed for my type?

Comment: Re *"if I explicitly say nil is allowed for my type"*:  – `nil` is an allowed value for the optional value of type `T?`, but not an allowed value for `T`. Unwrapping means: give me the wrapped `T` value . If there is none, it crashes.

Comment: For example: If you have `var opt: Int? = nil ; let i = opt!` – what result would expect if not a crash?

Comment: I expect i" would also equal to nil. But you are right i" isn't optional so it would crash. But unwrapping it shouldn't I thought but even if i" was optional, it still crash just because of the unwrapping.   However, I do get the fact that unwrapping makes the unwrapped value a non-optional.

Comment: It's like the compiler is like a five-year-old receiving a birthday present.. It _unwraps_ the gift, and expects to find something inside. When it does, everything is fine and happy. When it doesn't, it throws a fit and refuses to continue.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply put:** you wouldn't want your application to crash. Optionals are great for when you may or may not need a value, but you want to assign a variable to a type just in case.

It's similar to wearing a helmet when riding a bike. You may or may not fall during your ride (*assign a value*), but if you do, you sure will be happy that you've got a helmet (*prepared a variable*) for the situation. Now if you don't fall and find the helmet useless (*find `nil`*), you simply keep pedaling on (*handle for `nil` value*). This is what we tend to do in code. If we find a `nil` value, we handle it accordingly so the program doesn't crash.

There are many ways to handle a `nil` returned value in Swift. Some of these techniques include, but aren't limited to:

- [Nil Coalescing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)
- [Guard Statement](http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/)
- [If let Conditional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping an optional means getting the (non nil) value inside the Optional. If the optional contains `nil` then the crash is pretty correct.

There are several ways to conditionally unwrap an optional value

E.g.

```
let name: String? = nil
```

**if let**

```
if let name = name {
    print(name)
}
```

**guard let**

```
guard let name = name else { return }
print(name)
```

**inline conditional**

```
name?.uppercaseString
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent undefined behaviour. If you want to do something with a property, you expect it to contain something. And if it's accidentally nil at that point you should be aware of it and act accordingly. There might be cases when trying to do something with a nil (if the app doesn't crash), the whole flow could just stuck.